# choosing keys for the memcached data

Tags: memcached

I need to store different types of data into memcached

- sessions
- html for pages
- result for db queries
- user information
- site themes data
- some other types of objects

I need to know what's the right way to choose keys.

Specifically, for sessions, should I set the session ID as the key? What if in future I increase the length of the session ID so that exceeds the `250` limit for keys?

Answer (score 1):

Memcached does not allow you to do namespace based operations, therefore until you have a client side logic, the nomenclature of the keys don't have much impact.

As for the different types of data being set in the same memcached.
Memcached divides the memory into chunks of specific sizes according to the data being set.
Therefore if the data size distribution is large then the memcached wouldn't optimally utilize the space.

Please refer to the link below for deep understanding of the allocation system.

http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2011/02/06/memcache-internals/